# VM Can access internet but cannot download?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I have a host with Windows 10 hosting a VM with Windows 7 using VMWare 15.1.  I have the network settings set to "Bridged", it's a wired connection, and on the VM I am able to browse the internet fine.  The IPv4 is obtained automatically.  I can answer any other relevant questions as I have access to the VM and host, and I am not entirely sure what is relevant to answering this.

I was trying to install MySQL 5.6 via MySQL Installer, and when it tries downloading, I keep getting the message: `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.`

I have no idea why this is.  Any explanation or fix for this?

I am admittedly new to VM's and networking them so any resources are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you download a regular file via browser (like ie or chrome?)

What version of .NET are you running? If it's older then .NET 4.6, you will need to add the following lines to add the connection protocol to accept TLS1.2... or just upgrade your .NET version to 4.6 and above, and you should be good to go:

request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Afterwards, execute it, then try to rerun the installer.

Comment: I can download regular files via chrome, just tested it.  Will look into the .NET stuff now.

Comment: That did solve that particular error!  Now when MySQL tries to download, I get "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." which is a new error, so progress at least.

Comment: Can you try to remove "SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;" from the line i provided?? I assume its trying to connect using older TLS version which is depricated.

Comment: I've seen that advice in a bunch of google answers.  However, I don't know where the file or line is that I am supposed to be doing that is.  Where exactly do I go to make that change?  I suspect you are correct it will fix it.

Comment: You use powershell command "public static System.Net.SecurityProtocolType SecurityProtocol"

Answer (score 0):

I have that same configuration here.  In the Windows 7 virtual machine, browse internet and download works fine. Make sure MySQL 5.8 can be installed on another Windows 7 machine. Then:

1. Make sure VMware Tools have been installed:  VMware Menu, VM, Install tools.
2. With no machine running, run VMware Network Editor, reset the network, restart the host computer and test the VMware machine